# Is it secure to save your passwords in Brave?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, privacy, password-management, brave

I was using [Brave](//brave.com/) on Android a few weeks ago (based on `Chrome/57.0.2987.108`), and let it save my password, only to be notified via some message after the fact that my password now belongs to Google / Google Chrome.

Is this a known issue?  When using Brave (across the various architectures) how can I make sure that my passwords will never be given to evil corporations to store as they please, especially without an advanced notice?

Comment: The way to make sure that your passwords are never given to evil corporations is generally by not entering them into browsers (effectively) made by said evil corporations. Not setting whatever browser you use to remember your passwords is probably the first step. Brave might be a "new" browser, but if it walks like chrome, quacks like chrome and smells like chrome it probably is still very much chrome.

Comment: It is new, but it's been around for a while, so, naturally, I thought that not giving away your passwords to Google would be one of the first changes ever made.  This question should serve as a warning to others.  As well as document at which points the situation no longer presents itself.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the question, it is good to know that we have "yet another Chrome browser" walking the block and what pitfalls currently befall it. I was just trying to give general advice. Pretty much though, without them creating their own expensive architecture to store and share passwords it doesn't surprise me that they fall back to storing it using the same place that their parent project does. Yeah it's lazy, but given the parent (and thousands of sibling) browser projects I'm not too surprised.

Answer (score 2):

Some developers are developing their own browser based on chrome,
but forgetting to change some code results in this type of situation.
it seems that your password is actually saved by Chrome under your google account.
to verify this, visit that site again in Chrome and try to log in .
if Chrome automatically fills username and password ,then you can be certain.

Answer (score 2):

Brave browser passwords are stored locally, on the device. They are not stored in a cloud server. Any user can verify this by testing it out himself via the method kaushikC suggested in his comment. For more information, see this post: https://community.brave.com/t/brave-browser-password-manager-where-the-passwords-are-stored/36522